# Ipsec tunnel established, but no traffic or ping possible

Tags: routing, linux-networking, ipsec, strongswan

I have already searched for hours on this and many other sites and even though people have had similar issues, I haven't found one that can fix my problem.

I am trying to configure an IPsec tunnel from my computer to a virtual machine on a server using strongswan (by swanctl.conf). I have previously made the IPsec connection but from another device. I am using the same configuration (swanctl.conf)
but something else does not seem to fit. My machine (10.3.72.29) gets a virtual ip (172.13.14.2) and establishes a connection to the server's device (10.3.218.62) with its own virtual ip (192.168.122.2)

My current configuration:

My PC (Initiator) swanctl.conf:

```
connections {
   ch_vti0 {
      send_cert = always
      encap = yes
      vips = 0.0.0.0
      remote_addrs = 10.3.218.62
      local {
         round = 1
         id = 10.3.72.29
         auth = psk
         certs = 
       }
      remote {
         auth = psk
         id = 10.3.218.62
         certs = 
       }
      children {
        ch_vti0 { 
            mark_in = 42 
            mark_out = 42 
            remote_ts = 192.168.122.2/24
            local_ts = dynamic
            inactivity = 300s
            mode = tunnel
            esp_proposals =  3des-sha1-modp2048
            updown = /usr/local/etc/swanctl/updown.sh 0
         }
      }
      version = 1 
      proposals =  des-md5-modp768, des-md5-modp1024, des-md5-modp1536
   }  }
secrets {
        eap-xauth {
        eap_id = test1
        id = test1
        secret = password
   }
        xauth-local {
        id = test1
        secret = password
        }
        ike-sec {
        id = %any
        secret = test
        }
        ike-local {
        id = 10.3.72.29
        secret = test
        }
}
```

The server's virtual machine swanctl.conf:

```
connections {
   ch_vti0 {
      send_cert = always
      encap = yes
      pools = pools_users
      #aggressive = yes
      local {
         round = 1
         id = 10.3.218.62
         auth = psk
         certs = 
       }
      remote {
         auth = psk
         id = %any
         certs = 
       }
      children {
        ch_vti0 { 
            local_ts = 192.168.122.2/24
            inactivity = 120s
            mode = tunnel
            esp_proposals =  3des-sha1-modp2048
            updown = /usr/local/libexec/ipsec/_updown iptables
         }
      }
      version = 0
      proposals =  des-md5-modp768, des-md5-modp1024, des-md5-modp1536
   }  }
pools {
        pools_users {
                addrs = 172.13.14.2/24
        }
}
secrets {
        eap-xauth {
        eap_id = test1
        id = test1
        secret = password
   }
        xauth-local {
        id = test1
        secret = password
        }
        ike-sec {
        id = %any
        secret = test
        }
        ike-local {
        id = 10.3.218.62
        secret = test
        }
}
```

If anyone is wondering the updown.sh script creates the vti0 interface and routes

Result from ipsec statusall on my PC:

```
Listening IP addresses:
  10.3.72.29
  fdc8:c2cb:4586:cc11::8f00:5a9
  172.13.14.2
Connections:
     ch_vti0:  %any...10.3.218.62  IKEv1
     ch_vti0:   local:  [10.3.72.29] uses pre-shared key authentication
     ch_vti0:   remote: [10.3.218.62] uses pre-shared key authentication
     ch_vti0:   child:  dynamic === 192.168.122.0/24 TUNNEL
Security Associations (1 up, 0 connecting):
     ch_vti0[1]: ESTABLISHED 13 minutes ago, 10.3.72.29[10.3.72.29]...10.3.218.62[10.3.218.62]
     ch_vti0[1]: IKEv1 SPIs: 7fa996a60f87e923_i* 4faa8dbdd74a5927_r, rekeying in 3 hours
     ch_vti0[1]: IKE proposal: DES_CBC/HMAC_MD5_96/PRF_HMAC_MD5/MODP_768
     ch_vti0{1}:  INSTALLED, TUNNEL, reqid 1, ESP in UDP SPIs: c393a4bb_i c392a387_o
     ch_vti0{1}:  3DES_CBC/HMAC_SHA1_96/MODP_2048, 65772 bytes_i (783 pkts, 0s ago), 0 bytes_o, rekeying in 42 minutes
     ch_vti0{1}:   172.13.14.2/32 === 192.168.122.0/24
```

Server's device:

```
Listening IP addresses:
  192.168.122.2
  10.3.218.62
  fdc8:c2cb:4586:cc12::e49c:faf8
Connections:
     ch_vti0:  %any...%any  IKEv1/2
     ch_vti0:   local:  [10.3.218.62] uses pre-shared key authentication
     ch_vti0:   remote: [%any] uses pre-shared key authentication
     ch_vti0:   child:  192.168.122.0/24 === dynamic TUNNEL
Security Associations (1 up, 0 connecting):
     ch_vti0[1]: ESTABLISHED 14 minutes ago, 10.3.218.62[10.3.218.62]...10.3.72.29[10.3.72.29]
     ch_vti0[1]: IKEv1 SPIs: 7fa996a60f87e923_i 4faa8dbdd74a5927_r*, rekeying in 3 hours
     ch_vti0[1]: IKE proposal: DES_CBC/HMAC_MD5_96/PRF_HMAC_MD5/MODP_768
     ch_vti0{1}:  INSTALLED, TUNNEL, reqid 1, ESP in UDP SPIs: c392a387_i c393a4bb_o
     ch_vti0{1}:  3DES_CBC/HMAC_SHA1_96/MODP_2048, 0 bytes_i, 68880 bytes_o (820 pkts, 0s ago), rekeying in 44 minutes
     ch_vti0{1}:   192.168.122.0/24 === 172.13.14.2/32
```

Routes on my pc:

```
root@malz:/usr/local/etc/swanctl# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.3.127.1      0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp2s0
10.3.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     100    0        0 enp2s0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vti0
```

Routes on server's device:

```
root@server-automation-2:/etc/swanctl# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.3.127.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ens4
10.3.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 ens4
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ens3
```

I have allowed the ports that IPsec uses(500,4500,4500/udp,500/udp), tried disabling the firewalls on both of them, Cleared the iptables and allowed everything:

```
iptables -F
iptables -I INPUT -j ACCEPT
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
```

I have also checked the sysctl parameters for droping packets (especially those about icmp requests)

If I try to catch the packets with tcpdump
I can see I do receive them from the server's device (ping icmp packets)
but my PC doesn't respond

If I try to send packets the server's device doesn't catch them and my PC's IPsec interface TX error packets increase.
From ifconfig:

```
vti0: flags=209<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP>  mtu 1480
        inet 172.13.14.2  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 172.13.14.2
        inet6 fe80::5efe:a03:481d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        tunnel   txqueuelen 1000  (IPIP Tunnel)
        RX packets 1063  bytes 89292 (89.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 57  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 57  collisions 0
```

In conclusion, I have set up the ipsec connection between the two machines but I can't figure out why one of them can't transmit packages and doesn't respond to the others pings.
I am fairly certain the cause of all this isn't the ipsec configuration, because I have already previously mentioned I have tested it before and it works with the exact same conf file (excluding changing ips)

If anyone can give me even a hint I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps of troubleshooting (from bottom to top):

1. Run the tcpdump. You should see clear and encrypted packets (ESP).
2. Check the ip connectivity between ends of the ipsec tunnel.
3. Check the routing. By default the strongswan install the additional routes into a separate routing table. Run `ip -4 r ls table 220`. Investigate the output. To check the actual routes use the `ip route get <dst>` command. Don't use the `route -n` command - it returns the uncompleted view.
4. Check the output of `ip -s -s xfrm state list` and `ip -s -s -d xfrm policy list`. It shows the system SADB (Security Associations Data Base) and policy DB. Your vti interface has some carrier errors. Carrier error on the vti interface means:

   - no suitable ipsec policy has found. Check the `ip x p get ...` command.
   - no suitable route has found. Check the `ip route get ...` command.
   - no suitable SA has found. Check the `ip x s ls` command.
5. Check the firewall. The iptables command by default works with the `filter` table, but there are other tables (raw, nat, mangle). Better use the `iptables-save -c` command to list the full rule set. After the changing of the nat rules clear the conntrack table with the `conntrack -F` command. The ipsec traffic passes the firewall chains twice: one pass as encrypted, other pass as clear. So investigate the rules. Also you can insert the `NFLOG` target rules to capture the traffic with `tcpdump -ni nflog...` command.

Comment: Yes using the "ip route get" commands gave me a better understanding of the routes and helped me understand where the problem is coming from.

The problem was (and still is), that when I use 
swanctl --initiate --ike ch_vti0 --child ch_vti0        - the command that initiates the ipsec connection I get my virtual ip assigned on the interface vti0 as planned, but I also get it assigned on my primary interface enp2s0, therefore after I try to reach the other side of the tunnel it goes through my main interface. (Work around to the problem clear the table {ip route flush table 220})

Comment: This problem is already resolved, but the issue with the TX errors still remains and I think this creates a problem with my dpd keep alive the connection requests.

I checked everything you mentioned here and in a recent coment about the TX errors. 
I have the policies for forwarding, output and input.
I have the route through the correct interface.
I checked the SA states and everything seems correct.

I can ping the other machine and create requests, etc, but when I just leave it alone I doesn't send dpd requests to stay alive (Instead TX error increase)
Do you have any other ideas ?

Comment: You can run the `ip -t x monitor` and analyze the output later. Maybe errors are related with the rekey process.